# how to set the orientation of image in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, image

Can any one tell me that how can I set the image orientation or check by which I can keep the change image in the potrait form from other orientation

Thanks

Rohit

Answer (score 1):

Try `imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:` and `imageOrientation` property of UIImage. Works on iOS 4.0 and higher though.